# trying to return nil if a certain type passed to function in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, return, switch-statement

HI related to an earlier question which I kind of made a mess of so re posting. What I need to do is return nil if a certain type of blog post is passed into my function

this is the class instance that I am passing in

```
class BlogPost {

    var type = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))
    var views : Int?
    var author : String
    var email : String
    var order : Int = 0

    init(author : String, email : String, order : Int) {

        self.author = author
        self.email  = email
        self.order = order

    }

    func teaser() -> (authorName : String, numberOfViews : Int) {

        author = ""
        views = 0

        if views == 0 {
            println("no one has read your blog yet")
        } else {
            println("\(author) has \(views)")
        }

        return(author, views!)
    }
}
```

and this is the function which I am having a problem with

```
func randomViews(blog : BlogPost?)  {
    var vids = types[2]

    if blog?.type == vids {
        return nil
    } else {
        let viewCount : [Int] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

        var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(viewCount.count)
        var unsignedRandom = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
        var random = unsignedRandom

        switch (random) {
        case 10:
            println("Nil")
        case 10, 20 :
            println("0")
        default:
            random
        }
    }
}
```

the error I receive is

```
 "$T4?? does not conform to protocol '_RawOptionSetType'"
```

hope this is clearer than before and hope you can help.
Many thanks

no probs here is my types array

```
let types : [String] = ["technology", "memos", "animals"]
```

I have no also dropped the Int and updated the type within blog class

```
var type = (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))
```

basically if "animals" is passed in as a blog type I need to return nil otherwise do nothing and just carry on. So just need to know what return type would be best to use?   thanks

cheers Rob ok this is what I did I just created a seperate function to access a random element of the array

```
func randType() -> String {

var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(types.count)
var unsignedrandom = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
var random = Int(unsignedrandom)

return types[random]
}
```

then as you said no need for a return type just return

```
func randomViews(blog : BlogPost?)  {

var vids = types[2]

if blog?.type == vids {

    //println("NIL")
    return


} else {

let viewCount : [Int] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(viewCount.count)
var unsignedRandom = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
var random = unsignedRandom

switch (random) {

case 10:
    println("Nil")
case 10, 20 :
    println("0")
default:
    random

        }

      }

  }
```

this seems to work so I ll go with for now. Sorry for the dragged out post but at least I hung in there , didnt quit and got it going (somewhat)   thanks

Comment: In your `default` clause, you have just `random`. Did you mean `println(random)`? What did you want to do with `random` on this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. You've defined `BlogPost.type` to be an `Int`. But I presume that `types` is still defined as `[String]`. You need to make sure these two match.

   For example, now that you've defined `type` to be `Int`, you might want `if blog?.type == 2` rather than `if blog?.type == types[2]`. You don't want to compare your numeric `type` to a string, but rather to the number `2`.
2. You haven't specified any return type in your definition of `randomViews`, but you try to do `return nil`. What do you want `randomViews` to return (if anything)? Make sure your function's return type matches what you supply in the `return` statements.

Comment: no worries still cant get it work just not sure what the return type should be. Been on this all day so frustrating when your starting out. I want to return nil if that spefic blog post is selected . I will get there

Comment: There are two completely different problems in your code. One is the comparison (you should compare your numeric `type` against the number `2`, not against the string `types[2]`). The second is the function's return type. I see nothing here that suggests that the caller needs a return value from `randomViews` function, so I'd leave it as you had it, with no return type, and change the `return nil` to just `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `randomViews` is not specifying the return type:

```
func randomViews(blog : BlogPost?) -> UInt32? {
```

I presume it's a `UInt32?` because that is what I see in the `else` branch.

Moreover, the `else` branch is missing a `return` statement, which I presume should be `random`. The fixed function should look like:

```
func randomViews(blog : BlogPost?) -> UInt32? {
    var vids = types[2]

    if blog?.type == vids {
        return nil
    } else {
        let viewCount : [Int] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

        var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(viewCount.count)
        var unsignedRandom = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
        var random = unsignedRandom

        switch (random) {

        case 10:
            println("Nil")
        case 10, 20 :
            println("0")
        default:
            random
        }

        return random
    }
}
```

Comment: And I think that `random` is compared to one of the array objects, so it should be `random = viewCount[unsignedRandom]`, right?

Comment: Right - `RawOptionSetType` is one of a handful of nil-literal convertibles, so it gets flagged in the error on that `return nil` line.